# flow: cast mixed type to an array of shape

Tags: flowtype, mixed

I need to cast a mixed type to a shaped array in flow. [Tryflow link](https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAhgZQBZ2gEwIICctzDAXhm1zAB4BvOALgGcQsBLAOwHMBfAPgG5hgYA9AKgAPEFCzM4AG2n40UAGYsoaGOGjAAxgHtm9dbn2KdWALaEYACgCU1M4xGrCnGAG0q1GAHIkUWTre7AC6vNp6BgBGlgxwxqZmtryMitYkeAB0jLTpYFaRNjYwFMAAkLr6IPBeiCjouZaRvOx8MDD8MEA).

```
type aShapedArray = Array<{a:string}>;

 //externally defined type
const transform = ():mixed => [{a: 'hello'}];

const b = transform();
if (Array.isArray(b)) {
    const a: aShapedArray = b;
}
```

The error is

```
9:  const a: aShapedArray = b;
                            ^ array. Has some incompatible type argument with
9:  const a: aShapedArray = b;
             ^ aShapedArray
Type argument `T` is incompatible:
7: const b = transform();
             ^ mixed. This type is incompatible with
2: type aShapedArray = Array<{a:string}>;
                             ^ object type
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the only answer I found is to add an `any` cast to the array. Which pretty much equivalent to `flow: ignore this line`.

```
/* @flow */

type aShapedArray = Array<{a:string}>;

//externally defined type
const transform = ():mixed => [{a: 'hello'}];

const b: any = transform();
if (Array.isArray(b)) {
  const a: aShapedArray = b;
}
```

try flow: [link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCGAygBaH4AmAggE62FZgC8YdDWAPAN6EBcAZwy0AlgDsA5gF8AfAG50YYMDwAPDHlpjCMGE0p4o4vJTDZ8qAMZwxQsw1tQ4tALYswACgCUfFyNUmLDJgANq8fGAA5KR4unCRUgC6ClY2dgBGEYRiTKzC2QJOrt4KIlCe7IwAdCIClVge6V5eYNyoAJDWthhEWWQUJvXu6QpSimBAA)